# Google Maps Embedded KML/KMZ File with Search Box

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to connect the search box to my embedded Google map but the code I've acquired really doesn't allow the search of the KML/KMZ file. I'm struggling as this my first time using their API

I'm able to display the KMZ file without the searchbar but I'm unable to find a tutorial on implementing a search tool for the KMZ file as it's downloaded from My Maps on Google

```
   <style>
      html, body {
        height: 370px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
      #map {
       height: 360px;
       width: 300px;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
       border: thin solid #333;
       }
      #capture {
       height: 360px;
       width: 480px;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
       background-color: #ECECFB;
       border: thin solid #333;
       border-left: none;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        <div id="map"></div>


     <script>       var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        }); </script>
    <div id="capture"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var src = 'http://firework.com.au/map.kmz';

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
          var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
          var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
          testimonial.innerHTML = content;
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC1n-Z_9yO1OAylAowGQa9pcorepEEw2js&callback=initMap">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add google map api one time

I have added `&callback=initMapFunctions` in url of script tag which initialize `initMap()` and `initAutocomplete()` functions respectively

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
}


var map;
var src = 'http://firework.com.au/map.kmz';

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });
  kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
    var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
    testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });

}

function initMapFunctions() {
  initMap();
  initAutocomplete();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 370px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 360px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  border: thin solid #333;
}

#capture {
  height: 360px;
  width: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ECECFB;
  border: thin solid #333;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC1n-Z_9yO1OAylAowGQa9pcorepEEw2js&callback=initMapFunctions&libraries=places">
</script>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="capture"></div>
```